# Python can't use a function being called from another file

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have these two functions in a file that I am trying to use from a separate python file.

My main file setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'my_path')
    from functions_py import * #Useful python functions saved in a different script
```

Separate file with functions:

```
def global_pd_dfs(pattern=None, return_values=False):
    dct = globals()
    if pattern is None:
        return [dct[x] if return_values else x for x in dct.keys() if type(dct[x]) == pd.core.frame.DataFrame]
    else:
        pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        return [dct[x] if return_values else x for x in dct.keys() if type(dct[x]) == pd.core.frame.DataFrame and pattern.match(x)]


def multi_merge(pattern=None):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on=None), global_pd_dfs(pattern=pattern, return_values = True))
```

When I run from my main file, it returns an error:

```
df = multi_merge("^m_")

TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

However, it works perfectly fine when I run the functions from my main script. Why is this?

Comment: Every module has its own `globals()`.

Comment: What do you expect `global_pd_dfs` to return? You have no global `DataFrame`s defined in `functions_py`, and so `global_pd_dfs` returns an empty collection.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, merge all df's that have a column beginning with `m_`?

Comment: My `DataFrame` s are created from my main file, and are stored in my variable explorer. I am running all my code from the same IPython console, so I expected that when calling `global_pd_dfs` from the same console where `DataFrame` s were created in, it would match them.

Comment: Close, just all df's that begin with 'm_'. @Barmar
Sorry, I edited as I misread.

Comment: Searching through all global variables is a horrible way to do it. If you need to do something to all your dataframes, you should keep them in an explicit list.

Comment: In response to your first comment, when I run `globals()` they are still recognised no matter what file I run it from, so my global variables are actually shared. @Barmar